# Issues with multiprocessing and motor power with Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to use multiprocessing in Python to run a flask server in a Raspberry Pi. The reason for using multiprocessing is that I need to (at the same time) constantly check if a boundary has been reached (using opencv and a camera) as well as control a small car from a pc.

The code I had for just controlling the motors used Threading and worked as expected. However, the updated version uses multiprocessing and the motors behave as if they are not being given enough power to move the car.

The original code is:

```
import cv2
from picamera import PiCamera
import io
import threading
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO          
from time import sleep


in1 = 23
in2 = 24
en_a = 25
in3 = 17
in4 = 27
en_b = 22
temp1 = 1

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(in1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en_a,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.setup(in3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in4,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en_b,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)

power_a = GPIO.PWM(en_a,1000)
power_b = GPIO.PWM(en_b,1000)

power_a.start(1)
power_b.start(1)


app = Flask(__name__)


def capture_frame(camera):
    success, frame = camera.read()
    if not success:
        print("failed to read frame")
        return None
    else:
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        if not ret:
            return None
        frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
        return frame_bytes
    
    
def generate_image(camera):
    if camera == "usb_camera":
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        image = capture_frame(camera)
        camera.release()
    elif camera == "pi_camera":
        camera = PiCamera()
        camera.start_preview()
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
        stream.seek(0)
        image = stream.read()
        camera.stop_preview()
        camera.close()
    if image:
        yield (image)
        # The format below is to be able to see the image from a browser
        # yield (b'--frame\r\n'
        #        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + image + b'\r\n')
            

@app.route('/video-usb')
def video_usb():
    return Response(generate_image("usb_camera"), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/video-raspi')
def video_raspi():
    return Response(generate_image("pi_camera"), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    
    
@app.route('/move_forward', methods=['POST'])
def move_forward():
    power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
    power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.HIGH)
    return jsonify({"message": "Car moving forward"})
    
    
@app.route('/move_backward', methods=['POST'])
def move_backward():
    power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
    power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)
    return jsonify({"message": "Car moving backwards"})
    
    
@app.route('/move_right', methods=['POST'])
def move_right():
    power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
    power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)
    return jsonify({"message": "Car turning right"})
    
    
@app.route('/move_left', methods=['POST'])
def move_left():
    power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
    power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.HIGH)
    return jsonify({"message": "Car turning left"})
    

@app.route('/move_stop', methods=['POST'])
def move_stop():
    power_a.start(1)
    power_b.start(1)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)
    return jsonify({"message": "Car stopped"})


def start_server():
    app.run(host='192.168.100.36', port=8000, threaded=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    server_thread.join()
```

The modified version uses multiprocessing and I can see that the raspberry pi is getting the signal to enable the motors (a light turns on and the motors make a noise) but it's as if the motors were working with very low power for some reason. The code is:

```
import cv2
from picamera import PiCamera
import io
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO          
from time import sleep

import multiprocessing
import numpy as np


in1 = 23
in2 = 24
en_a = 25
in3 = 17
in4 = 27
en_b = 22
temp1 = 1

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(in1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en_a,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.setup(in3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in4,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en_b,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)

power_a = GPIO.PWM(en_a,1000)
power_b = GPIO.PWM(en_b,1000)

power_a.start(1)
power_b.start(1)


app = Flask(__name__)


def capture_frame(camera):
    success, frame = camera.read()
    if not success:
        print("failed to read frame")
        return None
    else:
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        if not ret:
            return None
        frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
        return frame_bytes
    return None
    
    
def generate_image(camera):
    if camera == "usb_camera":
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        image = capture_frame(camera)
        camera.release()
    elif camera == "pi_camera":
        camera = PiCamera()
        camera.start_preview()
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
        stream.seek(0)
        image = stream.read()
        camera.stop_preview()
        camera.close()
    if image:
        yield (image)
        # The format below is to be able to see the image from a browser
        # yield (b'--frame\r\n'
        #        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + image + b'\r\n')
            

@app.route('/video-usb')
def video_usb():
    return Response(generate_image("usb_camera"), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/video-raspi')
def video_raspi():
    return Response(generate_image("pi_camera"), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    
    
@app.route('/move_forward', methods=['POST'])
def move_forward():
    global local_allowed_movement
    
    if local_allowed_movement.value == 'no restriction':
        power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
        power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
        GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.HIGH)
        return jsonify({"message": "Car moving forward"})
    
    
@app.route('/move_backward', methods=['POST'])
def move_backward():
    global local_allowed_movement
    
    if local_allowed_movement.value == 'no restriction':
        power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
        power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
        GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)
        return jsonify({"message": "Car moving backwards"})
    
    
@app.route('/move_right', methods=['POST'])
def move_right():
    global local_allowed_movement
    
    if local_allowed_movement.value == 'no restriction' or local_allowed_movement.value == 'turn right':
        power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
        power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
        GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)
        return jsonify({"message": "Car turning right"})
    
    
@app.route('/move_left', methods=['POST'])
def move_left():
    global local_allowed_movement
    
    if local_allowed_movement.value == 'no restriction' or local_allowed_movement.value == 'turn left':
        power_a.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
        power_b.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
        GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.HIGH)
        return jsonify({"message": "Car turning left"})
    

@app.route('/move_stop', methods=['POST'])
def move_stop():
    power_a.start(1)
    power_b.start(1)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)
    return jsonify({"message": "Car stopped"})


def start_server(shared_allowed_movement):
    global local_allowed_movement
    local_allowed_movement = shared_allowed_movement
    
    app.run(host='192.168.100.36', port=8000, threaded=True)


def get_image():
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.start_preview()
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
    stream.seek(0)
    image = stream.read()
    camera.stop_preview()
    camera.close()
    image_bytes = np.frombuffer(image, dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(image_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image

    
def turn_direction(hsv, shared_allowed_movement):
    lower_blue = np.array([90, 50, 0], dtype = "uint8") # lower limit of blue color
    upper_blue = np.array([120, 255, 255], dtype="uint8") # upper limit of blue color
    height, width, depth = hsv.shape
    width_cutoff = width // 2
    left_side = hsv[:, :width_cutoff]    
    right_side = hsv[:, width_cutoff:]
    mask_1 = cv2.inRange(left_side, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    mask_2 = cv2.inRange(right_side, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    left_pixel_count = np.sum(mask_1)
    right_pixel_count = np.sum(mask_2)
    if left_pixel_count > right_pixel_count:
        shared_allowed_movement.value = 'turn right'
        print('\nTURN RIGHT!!!!!!!!!!\n')
    else:
        shared_allowed_movement.value = 'turn left'
        print('\nTURN LEFT!!!!!!!!!!\n')


def detect_boundary(hsv, shared_allowed_movement):
    global allowed_movement

    lower_blue = np.array([90, 50, 0], dtype = "uint8") # lower limit of blue color
    upper_blue = np.array([120, 255, 255], dtype="uint8") # upper limit of blue color
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    edge_pixels = np.sum(mask)
    if edge_pixels > 350:
        turn_direction(hsv, shared_allowed_movement)
    else:
        shared_allowed_movement.value = 'no restriction'


def boundary_detection(shared_allowed_movement):   
    while (True):
        image = get_image() 
        print("detecting if boundary has been reached")
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        detect_boundary(hsv, shared_allowed_movement)


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    shared_allowed_movement = manager.Value("c", "no restriction")
    
    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_server, args=(shared_allowed_movement,))
    boundary_detection_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=boundary_detection, args=(shared_allowed_movement,))
    
    server_process.start()
    boundary_detection_process.start()
    
    server_process.join()
    boundary_detection_process.join()
```

I tried commenting the boundary_detection_process statements to just run the motor controls but the motor behavior remains exactly the same. If I run the old script again, it still behaves as expected (the motors are given the expected power).

If anyone has any ideas I could try out, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Multiprocessing supports [two](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) ways of sharing data between processes. A global variable is not one of them, as the global variable is local to the process and when you have two processes, the global variables are not global to both processes.

Comment: Thanks but I was already aware of this. If you take a look at the script, you'll see that the global variable is used only with server_process and its child processes.

Comment: "shared_allowed_movement" works as expected.

Also, this is not related to the issue since I've mentioned that the issue is the motor controls themselves. The signal is indeed sent to the motors but it seems that the power is too low.